# CIFilter not working

Tags: ios, swift, core-image

I'm trying to add a blur effect to a layer with following code.
 But it doesn't work, any advise?

```
let layer = CALayer()
layer.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 150, width: 150, height: 150)
layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
layer.contents = UIImage(named: "D1")?.cgImage

if let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: ["inputRadius": 15]) {
filter.setDefaults()
layer.filters = [filter]
}
view.layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

It just displayed the image without filter effect. I'm really confused. Thank you for any advise.

Comment: What happens if you comment out filter.setDefaults()?

Comment: @LouisLeung It would be the same with or without `filter.setDefaults()` .

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't work on iOS. From the [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410901-filters) documentation:

> **Special Considerations**
>
> This property is not supported on layers in iOS.

You'll need to do it the ["long"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9701358/applying-a-cifilter-to-a-calayer) way:

```
let ciInput = CIImage(image: UIImage(named: "D1")!)
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur", withInputParameters: ["inputImage": ciInput, "inputRadius": 15])
let ciOutput = filter?.outputImage
let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciOutput!, from: (ciOutput?.extent)!)
layer.contents = cgImage
```

Please note that my Swift 4 code is untested. One or two build issues (unwrapping in particular) may be there and (of course) due to this a `nil` may happen at runtime. I'm providing the Swift code as a good translation of the accepted answer in the question linked to above.

Comment: yeah this pretty much works! note that with this method the blur creates a fuzzy border around the content with the distance of roughly the inputRadius you input... i fixed this with a patch solution (taking it into account in the frame..)