# How to apply a CoreImage filter to a view?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-image

Is there a simple way to apply a CoreImage filter to the content of a view? For example make a view look blurry?

Comment: I believe you can render your views calayer and then apply the filter to that image.

Comment: As a note, there are currently no blur filters in Core Image on iOS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528726/does-ios-5-support-blur-coreimage-fiters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can convert the UIView to UIImage and then apply CoreImage filters on it..

you can use the following code to convert it..

```
+ (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4334902/919545)