# CICategoryBlur not found in built in filters in CoreImage

Tags: objective-c, filter, core-image, built-in

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does iOS 5 support blur CoreImage fiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528726/does-ios-5-support-blur-coreimage-fiters)

I would like to use the fitler in CICategoryBlur, however when I search for filters in kCICategoryBlur I can't find any filters. I finally did a search for all built in filters and I wasn't able to find any filters for the blur category and it seemed to be missing a number of filters I expected to be part of built in.

Here's the code I used to find the filters, there's nothing special. But with this I can only find 48filters.

Anyone know what might be my issue?

```
NSMutableArray  *filtsInCat = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
filtsInCat = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[CIFilter filterNamesInCategory:kCICategoryBuiltIn]];

NSLog(@"filter count: %i",[filtsInCat count]);
for (int i=0; i<[filtsInCat count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"filter name: %@", [filtsInCat objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

thanks

Comment: my mac ox is 10.7.2 and using ios sdk 5.0

Answer (score 2):

The set of filters available in iOS is only a subset of those available in OS X.

See also

[Does iOS 5 support blur CoreImage fiters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528726/does-ios-5-support-blur-coreimage-fiters)