# how to add Spherical Filter Effect (a fish eye) on UIImage in objective - C in iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, image-processing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS images in a bubble effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614162/ios-images-in-a-bubble-effect)

I want to add a fish eye filter effect on UIImage in iphone App. on googling i get the effect like spherical image effect with vignette image effect. I have completed vignette effect but can't implement Spherical Image effect. Can any one suggest how to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: This is nice task, but a though one

Comment: It doesn't look like the CIFilters you need are yet available on iOS. You could try writing a glsl shader to do it.

Comment: You could use the CIBumpDistortion effect to get a similar effect with some tweaking. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIBumpDistortion