# How to cut texture to custom shape in OpenGLES?

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, opengl-es-2.0, shapes

I want to achieve the result like in the image below:
[image]

I assume, solutiuon is:

1. Cut the custom shape.
2. Scale received shape.
3. Apply blur to main texture.
4. Draw the shape on top.
5. Draw the real transparent drop on the top of shape.

My question is how to cut the texture in drop shape using vertex and/or fragment shader? Appreciate any ideas and suggestions abot the way to go.

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11614991/19679 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11387757/19679 might be close to what you're looking for, with the replacement of the sphere there with your more complex shape.

Comment: @BradLarson It seems close to my goal. I'll check. Thanks.

Comment: @BradLarson How do you blur background texture here http://stackoverflow.com/a/11614991/19679?

Comment: Using a separable Gaussian blur, described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804732/gaussian-filter-with-opengl-shaders/9592454#9592454 and here: http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2013/10/21/optimizing-gaussian-blurs-mobile-gpu